# SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE with Python 3.11 When Accessing API

Tags: python, ssl, request

I recently upgraded my Python environment from 3.8 to 3.11 and encountered an SSL handshake issue when trying to access an external API, which worked fine in the previous version. The error I'm receiving is: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE. This occurs when my function tries to post a request to the API.

Here's the function I'm using:

my fucntion:

```
def get_gush_helka_api(city,street,home_number):
    headers = {
    }
    if pd.isna(city) or pd.isna(street):
        return None
    city = city.strip()
    street = street.strip()
    home_number = str(home_number).strip()

    address = f"{city} {street} {home_number}" if home_number else f"{city} {street}"
    json_data = {
        'whereValues': [
            address,
        ],
        'locateType': 2,
    }
    result = {}

    retries = Retry(total=3, backoff_factor=0.5, status_forcelist=[500, 502, 503, 504])
    adapter = HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retries)
    session = requests.Session()
    session.mount('https://', adapter)
    try:
        response = requests.post('https://ags.govmap.gov.il/Search/ParcelLocate', headers=headers, json=json_data)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            json_obj = response.json()
            if json_obj['errorCode'] == 0 and json_obj['status'] == 0:
                try:
                    result = {
                        'gush': int(json_obj['data']['ResultData']['Values'][0]['Values'][0]),
                        'helka': int(json_obj['data']['ResultData']['Values'][0]['Values'][1]),
                    }
                except:
                    result = {
                        'gush':0,
                        'helka':0,
                    }
            return result
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print(f"An error occurred with {e}")

    return None
```

I suspect the issue is related to changes in SSL/TLS protocol handling in Python 3.11, but I'm not sure how to adapt my code to address this. The server I'm trying to connect to may have specific SSL/TLS requirements.

Questions:

Are there known SSL/TLS compatibility issues with Python 3.11?
How can I modify my code to fix the SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE error while maintaining a secure connection?
Is there a way to specify SSL/TLS protocol versions or cipher suites in Python 3.11 to comply with server requirements?
Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Please reduce your code to the bare minimum needed to reproduce your problem. If I do  a `r = requests.get('https://ags.govmap.gov.il/')` it works for me with Python 3.11. See also [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).